# How can a string literal be used as other lvalues?

Tags: c

A string literal is an lvalue.

An lvalue can be used:

1. as the operand of the address-of operator (except if the lvalue designates a bit field or was declared register).
2. as the operand of the pre/post increment and decrement operators.
3. as the left-hand operand of the member access (dot) operator.
4. as the left-hand operand of the assignment and compound assignment operators.
5. as ... (anything which a value can be used as but I miss to list)

I was wondering how a string literal can be used as operands of the above operators in a C program?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it help to say string literals are read-only lvalues?

Comment: C99 and later (or earlier with extension) provide the *compound literal* which allows you to use a bit of *slight-of-hand* (or *programming legerdemain*) to create a modifyable lvalue where a literal would otherwise be created, e.g. `char *literal = (char[]){"my string literal"};`. Yes it's just an array, but it is also a literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bullets 2 and 4 require a *modifiable lvalue* , which excludes arrays. String literals are arrays, so they are not modifiable lvalues.

The first one is OK, `&"hello"` is allowed, although this would be an uncommon usage.

The third one, the left-hand side of `.` must have struct type, which a string literal doesn't. However, note that the left-hand operand of `.` does not actually need to be an lvalue.